# Eclipse built-in shell

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, interpreter

Does Eclipse come with a built-in interpreter? If not is there anything like IDLE for Python Shell that is lightweight and *just* works?

I have already tried Groovy but I need something that is strictly Java, and I don't quite like Beanshell.

Comment: Python is an interpreted language. Interpreted languages lend themselves very well to interactive prompts. Java is compiled. Anything that comes close to interactive will be a hack at best.

Comment: No wonder I can't find anything *good*. ):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Eclipse Scrapbook Pages](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61137.html)

Comment: Although outdated and unpractical, that seems to be the closest bet.

Comment: @ChristopherM "Although outdated and unpractical, that seems to be the closest bet." is exactly how I feel about Java most of the time.